# How to prove the diagonal subgroup is a normal subgroup implies that group is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and consider the subgroup $H=\{(g,g)\mid g \in G\}$ of $G\times G$. Show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G\times G$, then $G$ is abelian. (Hint: consider $(a,e) \in  G\times G$ and $(h,h) \in H$.)

I'm not sure how to prove this since $(a,e)(h,h)=(h,h)(a,e)$ isn't implied even if its a normal subgroup. Is there another way to attack this with the hint given?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $H \unlhd G$. Then for all $(a,b)\in G\times G$, $(a,b)H(a,b)^{-1}=H$. In particular, if we choose $(a,b)=(a,e) \in G \times G$ and $(h,h) \in H$, then $(a,e)(h,h)(a,e)^{-1}\in H$, so it equals $(k,k)$ for some $(k,k) \in H$. Thus
\begin{align*}
(a,e)(h,h)(a,e)^{-1}&=(k,k)\\
(a,e)(h,h)(a^{-1},e^{-1})&=(k,k)\\
(aha^{-1},ehe^{-1})&=(k,k).
\end{align*}
Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: Yes thats the part I got stuck on I'm not sure how to prove G is abelian from that last step, the farthest I ever got was ah=ka which I thought wasn't helpful since h doesn't necessarily equal k.

Comment: Look at the second coordinate: you must have $ehe^{-1}=k$. What does that tell you?

Comment: Note that $e$ is the group identity element.

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe I didn't see that thanks so much.

Comment: And now finally you can extend $H$ to $G$ to complete the result.